# How to update user password and store inside the database using django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to allow the admin to update the staff password, email address and username but the new password, email address and username is not updated into my database, did I do anything wrong in the code?

The images below is how the main page looks like:
[image]

This images show the next page which is the page that the staff password, username and email address will be updated:
[image]

views.py

```
def update(request, id):
    context = {}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":

        user.save()
        return redirect("/allstaff")
    return render(request, 'allstaff.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #path('login/', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('adminpage/', views.admin, name='adminpage'),
    path('customer/', views.customer, name='customer'),
    path('logistic/', views.logistic, name='logistic'),
    path('forget/', views.forget, name='forget'),
    path('newblock/', views.newblock, name='newblock'),
    path('quote/', views.quote, name='quote'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('adminprofile/', views.adminprofile, name='adminprofile'),

    path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('allstaff/', views.allstaff, name='allstaff'),
    path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
    path('edit-register/', views.edit_register_view, name='edit_register'),


]
```

updatestaff.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .button {
  background-color: #38d39f;
  border-color: #38d39f;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 275px;
}
    </style>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

    <title>Forget Password</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-6 contents">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-25">
              <div class="form-block">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                </div>

              <h2>Password reset</h2>
                <br/>
                <form method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <h4>Having trouble signing in?</h4>
                  <p>Follow the steps below to get started</p>


                    <label for="Username">Username:</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
                 <label for="Email">Email:</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email"><br>
                  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>
                  <label for="con-pass">Confirm Password:</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="con-pass" name="con-pass"><br><br>

                  <button class="button" >Submit</button>

                  <br>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a dedicated type for password input in HTML you should consider using for storing passwords in post reqeusts.
`<input type="password">`

To your question,
In order to update user password, you should use user.set_password method.
Check [this documentation here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)
The link above also shows you how to change other properties of a user.

In your `views.py` file, you are not accepting requested data from the form.
So, do this. Here's how:

```
def update(request, id):
    context = {}
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # getting form input values from your HTML Form.
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('Email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user.username = username
        user.email = email
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return redirect("/allstaff")
    return render(request, 'allstaff.html', context)
```

I hope this is your answer.

Comment: let me check out the documentation you send me

Comment: Hi, I have try changing to yours but it is still not working, I cant update my password inside my database

Comment: I still cannot update my password and store it in the database after following your advice, any other help ?

Comment: Are you trying to change passwords directly from the database?
In that case, I'm not sure if you can do it without disabling password hashing.

Comment: Django doesn't save plain passwords, it encrypts your password then saves it.

Comment: I am trying to change password on the website and restore it into the database